# WordPress CFDB generate unique sequence number

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm working on a way to generate unique sequence number from the database using sevensparks method & contact form DB change form data method to achieve this currently

http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-counter-for-contact-form-7

http://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=747

The count is working, but the problem is whenever there are few users who submit the form with the pre entered values in the hidden text field, I will receive multiple submission of the same id.

**eg. 0012, 0012, 0014, 0015, 0015, 0017**

So i figured adding a while loop for checking the values in cfdb would be better, however it's still not getting there.  Is there anyway to achieve this?

eg. Before saving a number, check with database. If number exists add an increment; if doesn't exist save new number.

```
//Define the key to store in the database
define( 'CF7_COUNTER', 'cf7-counter' );

//Create the shortcode which will set the value for the DTX field
function cf7dtx_counter(){
    $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;  //Increment the current count
    return $val;
}
add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

//CFDB change form data before it is saved
function update_counter($formData) {
    // Change $formData
    $formName = 'Contact form 1'; // change this to your form's name
    if ($formData && $formName == $formData->title) {

        while ( $val === get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) ) {
            $val++;
            return $val;
        }
        update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val); //Update the settings with the new count

    }
    return $formData;
}
add_filter('cfdb_form_data', 'update_counter');`
```

Comment: i realized wordpress update_option or add_option isn't working so well when handling multiple submissions at the same time. Is there any workaround for this?